# If $Y|X \sim N(0,1)$, does that mean $Y$ itself is also $N(0,1)$?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, expected-value

If $Y|X \sim N(0,1)$, does that mean $Y$ itself is also $N(0,1)$?

It looks like it as I can write
$$
E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[0] = 0,
$$
and
$$
Var[Y] = Var[E[Y|X]] + E[Var[Y|X] = Var[0] + E[1] = 1. 
$$
But although I get the correct expectation and variance I don't see how we can say $Y$ is normally distributed?

If it is true, does this only hold because we are dealing with the normal distribution?

Comment: $Y|X$ has a distribution that is (a) independent from $X$ and (b) a Normal distribution. The conclusion does not involve any specifics of the Normal distribution.

Comment: Expression for marginal of $Y$: $Pr(Y \leq y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \Phi(y) f(x) dx$. Regardless of what $f(x)$ is it will integrate to one to give that $Pr(Y \leq y) = \Phi(y)$. So it's normal.

Comment: @Dayne What is $\Phi(y)$? And where did you get that expression for the probability of $Y$ being less than $y$. The definition of $Pr(Y \le y)$ is $Pr(Y \le y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(t) dt$ where $f_Y$ is the probability density function of $Y$.

Comment: $\Phi(y)$ is the cdf for standard normal. Since, $Y|X$ is standard normal, the marginal can be calculated as shown.